# Displaying a user's social media information

Tags: php, twitter, facebook

This is for a page where it displays some social media information for that user.

I would like to improve the following code that I posted below.  It does the job perfectly, but I just feel like it could definitely be improved.  I could easily leave it the way it is but I am trying to learn and that's why I would like to get suggestions from experienced programmers.

```
<?php
if($facebook && !$twitter_username || !$facebook && $twitter_username) {
    $width = "490";
} else {
    $width = "930";
}
?>

<div id="content">
<div style="width:<?=$width;?>px;margin:auto;">
    <?php if($facebook) { ?><div class="buttons"><img src="images/facebook_icon.png" class="fb" /> <p><em>Like Us</em><br />on Facebook</p></div><?php } ?>
    <?php if($twitter_username) { ?><div class="buttons"><img src="images/twitter_icon.png" class="twitter" /> <p><em>Follow Us</em><br />on Twitter</p><span>@<?=$twitter_username;?></span></div><?php } ?>
</div>
<br class="clear" />

<?php 
if($twitter_username) {
    if($display_tweets) {
 ?>
<div class="tweet">
    <h2 class="twitter_feed white_textshadow">Latest Tweet</h2>
    <div class="feed"></div>
</div>
<?php 
    }

} 
if(!$display_tweets || !$twitter_username) {
    if($website_url) { 
?>
    <h2 class="visit white_textshadow center"><em>Visit Our Website</em><br>www.<?=$website_url;?></h2>
<?php 
    }
}
?>
</div>
```

In the database there are 4 fields:

- Facebook (NULL or 1)
- Twitter username (NULL or username)
- display_feed (NULL or 1)
- Website URL (NULL or URL domain.com format)

Comment: Consider using a templating engine like twig: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Style (PHP)**

- At the beginning, the test seems pretty weird but in any case, I usually prefer

  ```
  $var = (condition) ? val1 : val2;
  ```

  over

  ```
  if(condition) {
      $var = val1;
  } else {
      $var = val2;
  }
  ```
- You can replace

  ```
  if(condition1) {
      if(condition2) {
          stuff();
      }
  }
  ```

  with

  ```
  if(condition1 && condition2) {
      stuff();
  }
  ```

On top of that, the `if(!$display_tweets || !$twitter_username)` test would then be useless as it would correspond to the `else` case.

- There's no point in closing php tags just before reopening them. Remove the `? > < ? php` tags.

**Style (HTML)**

- Do you really want to use the em markup inside the `h2` one?

**What you are actually doing/trying to do**

- The code at the beginning seems to be assuming that we have a least facebook or twitter (sometimes both).

  - If this is indeed the case, the
    `$width = ($facebook && !$twitter_username || !$facebook && $twitter_username) ? "490" : "930";`
    at the beginning could become
    `$width = ($facebook && $twitter_username) ? "930" : "490";`
  - If it is not the case, could the beginning be behind an `if (twitter || facebook)` test as creating an empty `div` (and giving it an arbitrary width) might not be relevant. If you want to keep it, for the definition of the width, I'd rather have someting like : 
    `$width = ($facebook && $twitter_username) ? "930" : (($facebook || $twitter_username) ? "490" : "1");`
- It might be interesting to use `<a href="<?= $website_url; ?>" >` or something like that to display the url as an actual link to make things easier from a user point of view (here I assumed that the input has been sanitized properly). On top of that, I don't understand why you hardcode the `www.` string (have a look at your current adress bar for more details). If there was anything to be hardcoded (and I personally wouldn't go for that), it's more likely to be the `http://` part.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  For the em inside the h2, I needed that part to be italics and then also that italicized part has a little bigger font size then the bottom part, so I can target it with CSS to increase the font size.  Is there a better way to do it?  And for the www, I am storing the domains as domain.com in the database and this screen will be shown on TV's so there are no clickable links or anything.  I just figured it would be best to display the website URL as www.domain.com - should I do it differently?

Comment: I would use a <span> or a <p> tag in the place of the em. Then apply a class to the new element rather than using em.